# Where does Xcode Organizer store iPhone screenshots?

Tags: iphone, xcode, screenshot, organizer

I've made a hundred of screenshots from iPhone thru Organizer but it looks like the only way to get actual files is by clicking on each screenshot and saving it. Is there any place on my Mac I can have them all? They are definitely stored somewhere -- all are listed in Organizer>Screenshots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There you go:

~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Screenshots

Comment: Sadly, once you have upgraded to Xcode 6, this location is removed. And equally unfortunately, I discovered that my system does not back up this location to the Time Machine.

So, if you have any good screenshots in Xcode 5 or under (I did), I'd suggest verifying they are preserved in your Time Machine, or back them up manually before upgrading to Xcode 6.  For more info on the Xcode 6 location, see 0x7ffffff's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question has changed as of Xcode 6. There is no longer a screenshots section in Xcode's Organizer. Instead, to take a screenshot, you have to navigate to Xcode's "Devices" window:

Window > Devices

or

<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (Used to be the shortcut for Organizer)

Here you can select your device from the list on the left and then press the "Take Screenshot" button. The screenshot's will now be saved directly to your ~/Desktop like they are when taking screenshots in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a screenshot in organizer, right click on the screenshot and click 'Show in finder'. Finder will open the screenshots folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just drag them out of Organizer to where ever you need them (Finder, Photoshop etc).